# Trying to enhance the query to give me results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 three scenarios

1. where there is no email - returns me empty
2. where there are multiple emails with one primary email - should return me primary
3. where there is multiple emails but no primary - should return me the first one

Here is my query I am trying

```
select * 
from departs 
left outer join answers on answers.fkdepartid =departs.departID
inner join emails on emails.userid = departs.userID 
    and emails.primary = 1
where departs.departid = 100
```

where I can add the logic of the above

Comment: Please provide data examples with table structures

Comment: Exactly how do you wish to determine which email is "the first one"? Bear in mind, sql tables have no implicit order, they're explicitly unordered sets. For there to be a "first one" you need to have rules that rely on data, such as; the email with the oldest created_date, or the email that's first alphabetically.

Comment: Do you have a date field to determine the first email?

Comment: not a date field but a ID field of the emails table

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the [`row_number()` windowing function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        row_number() over (
            partition by d.userID 
            order by case when e.primary = 1 then 0 else 1 end
        ) rn
    FROM departs d
    LEFT JOIN answers a on a.fkdepartid = d.departID
    INNER JOIN emails e ON e.userid = d.userID 
    WHERE d.departid = 100
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

An [`APPLY` lateral join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#using-apply) will also work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM departs d
LEFT JOIN answers a on a.fkdepartid = d.departID
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 * 
    FROM emails e0
    WHERE e0.userid = d.userID 
    ORDER BY case when e0.primary = 1 then 0 else 1 end
) e
WHERE d.departid = 100
```

`APPLY` tends to be slower, but I often find it easier to reason about, which can sometimes matter more than the raw performance.

Note both of these options are **NON-DETERMINISTIC**, which means they could return *different results* from one moment to the next. This is because there is not a complete definition of "first" for which email to use if none is primary. In database circles, non-deterministic queries and requirements are frowned upon and something to avoid.

To fix this (because it really is *broken* until you do) to be fully deterministic, add criteria to the `ORDER BY` clause to further define which email address you want.

Comment: Needs to be an OUTER join. Case 1 is where there are no emails present.

Comment: @MatBailie I took "returns me empty" to mean "no results". But I suppose you could read that to mean an empty string.

Comment: The wording -appears- (to me) to be referring to the email rather than entire row(s), but yes, the language barrier makes it very ambiguous

Comment: It's an easy change. If the OP clarifies, I can make it.

Comment: i world better apply order by because if none is primary the table which is emails has its own primary key, so the first one will be picked order by clause

Comment: @VueJS Not sure what you're saying, but primary key order isn't guaranteed, either. The server might use another index to better line up with the WHERE clause or a JOIN, for example. If it's not in the ORDER BY, it's not determined.